# Is this a new edit screen? Or have I just never seen it?

Tags: discussion, edits

Today I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29165460/57475), which a user commented on. [The comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164857/calculate-selling-price-to-achieve-at-least-10-profit#comment46550384_29165460) contained a link to an **edit** view of my post that I've never seen before. I don't seem to be able to access this view via any of the usual links available on the post, except directly via the url.

The url of the edit view is: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29165460/edit

The page looks like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

It contains:

- Drop down with revisions
- Question preview
- Editable answer box and preview

I'm not sure how or if this page is actually used? Any ideas?

Comment: Just middle click on any edit link.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can go to the revision history of a post and click `edit` on any of the revisions there, and it'll get you to that view.

The view is *not* new; it has been around for a *long* time, and it is the view used when editing on a mobile browser. I suspect it may even have been the default view before the current in-place editor was introduced.

Comment: wow, so it's just something I've never seen before.

Comment: The drop down at the top shows revisions, but changing the selection does nothing as far as I can see. Seems odd it being a drop down.

Comment: @Tanner: yeah, the select box just tells you in a compact manner what revision you are using as a base for your edit.

Comment: Actually, the easiest way to get to that screen is *not having the edit-privilige* and clicking on edit (thus not being able to inline-edit). The second possibility is pressing shift or opening in a new window/tab when selecting edit to force non-inline-editing. Though the revision-selector will only be shown when there are actually revisions.

Comment: @Deduplicator: right, shows you how long it's been for me since I gained the editing privilege.

Comment: @Dedup or, having editing privs, control clicking :)

Comment: Another way to get that is clicking "edit" while the page is still loading, before the event listeners have been added. This has happened to me multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

That's the default **non-inline** edit view, which is linked from every <kbd>edit</kbd> button.

It's only that the normal edit button has some javascript handler attached to it that opens an [*inline editor*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53916/183280), which you consider to be "normal" (it has been around since 2010). If you open the edit link in a new tab, follow the url manually, disable javascript, use the edit links in the revision history, use mobile browser, don't have edit privileges etc… you will see this default editor.